# How to get a pattern in svn logs ? (ticket number only)

Tags: shell, unix, svn, awk, sed

I need help with awk or any better way to get just the ticket number with a particular pattern as my output. For eg:

My log:

```
 svn log -v http://test.svn.com/svn/project1/trunk


r1 | testuser1 | 2014-11-10 17:25:08 -0500 (Mon, 10 Nov 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
A /trunk/file1
TR#:123456<issue>bug fix</issue>
```

Desired output:

```
TR#:123456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `grep -o`:

```
svn log -v http://test.svn.com/svn/project1/trunk | grep -o '^TR#:[0-9]*'
TR#:123456
```

Answer (score 0):

With **sed:**

```
svn log -v http://test.svn.com/svn/project1/trunk | sed -n '/TR#/s/<.*//p'
```

Print only line matching `TR#`, but remove everything from `<` till end

With **awk:**

```
svn log -v http://test.svn.com/svn/project1/trunk | awk '/TR#/{gsub(/<.*/,"");print}'
```

Print only line matching `TR#`, but substitute everything from `<` till end with `empty string`